# Change Activity's EditText from within an Adapter -> CustomView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

Basically, I have this structure:

> Activity -> RecyclerView Adapter -> Custom View

Below is my code (I've left some parts out to make it clearer).

Here is my Activity, MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private EditText textField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textField);

        // Adapter code
    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter, MyAdapter.java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "MyAdapter";

    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        CustomView customView = new CustomView(context);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(customView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //
    }

}
```

And here is my Custom View, CustomView.java:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    private final String TAG = "CustomView";

    private RelativeLayout mLayout;
    private ImageView mPicture;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_layout, this);

        this.mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        this.mPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

        mPicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // change text of EditText in Activity here
            }
        });
    }

}
```

What I want to be able to do is, if the user clicks `mPicture` in the Custom View, it should change the text of the EditText in my Activity to "Hello, world!".

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `EditText editText = (EditText) context.findViewById(R.id.textField);' ? In CustomView keep a reference to the context you ask for when making a new CustomView.

Comment: Later on, I want to make it so that it does different things under different contexts/activities. So in one activity, I might want to changed the text of an EditText, and in another activity, I might want to change the color of a button on the screen when the `mPicture` is clicked.

Comment: What about change your `adapter` to `abstract class` and create a new `abstract method` inside `adapter`, call the `abstract method` when `mPicture` is clicked, and then create your own implementation inside activity. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add an interface.

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    public interface PictureClickListener {
        public void onPictureClick();
    }

    private PictureClickListener listener;

    public setPictureClickListener(PictureClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    ...


        mPicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (CustomView.this.listener != null)
                    CustomView.this.listener.onPictureClick();
            }
        });
```

Set the interface and implement it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements PictureClickListener {

    @Override public void onPictureClick() {
        // change text of EditText in Activity here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Apapter code
        adapter.setPictureClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}
```

---

Note: This would be much easier without `CustomView`... Just have the `ViewHolder` inflate `R.layout.item_layout` and move the interface there.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v = inflater.inflate(....); // here

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mPicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MyAdapter.this.listener != null)
                MyAdapter.this.listener.onPictureClick();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've followed your suggestion, but the listener always seems to be `null` and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to use `setPictureClickListener`... But I wasn't really sure where to put that considering you had that CustomView class.

Answer (score 1):

First, you may inflate the custom view inside `onCreateViewHolder` method instead of create `CustomView` class. My solution for the problem is by changing your adapter to `abstract class` and create a new `abstract` method inside adapter. All you have to do is `override` the `abstract` method inside your activity.

```
//change adapter to abstract class
public abstract class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "MyAdapter";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //your data

    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false); //inflate the custom view

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(customView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       ViewHolder body = (ViewHolder) holder;
       body.populateView(); //you can also pass some parameters here
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size(); //size of your array
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private RelativeLayout mLayout;
        private ImageView mPicture;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.mLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            this.mPicture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        }

        public void populateView(){
            //set click listener to the picture
            this.mPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onPictureClick(); // call the abstract method
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //create new abstract method
    public abstract void onPictureClick();
}
```

in your activity (or fragment):

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext()) {
    @Override
    public void onPictureClick() { //override the abstract method
        //change edittext value here
        textField.setText("Hello World");
    }
};
```

Comment: exactly i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Change your textField from private to:

```
public static EditText textField;
```

in your CustomView you should be able to setText now:

```
mPicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.textField.setText("Hello World");
        }
    });
```

Comment: static view are bad, nasty memory leaks happen.